# Ready-made date picker in Javascript + HTML? (need: separate fields for DD, MM, YY plus calendar chooser)

Tags: javascript, html, calendar

I need such a form element: 3 separate drop-downs of Day, Month and Year, plus "calendar" button that shows calendar picker. Dropdowns should behave cleverly and know each other's state  (e.g., no 31 February should be possible and leap years should be handled correctly). Calendar picker should show a little calendar, where user would pick a date and the pick would be passed to drop-downs.

I appreciate if you point me to an existing solution.

I intent NOT to use ExtJS or similar high-end framework, more on JQuery level.

Comment: What about jQuery UI? It has a datepicker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search for jquery demos on datepicker.
You will find a lot of datepickers along with the source code. You can select among them.
I use the jquery UI datepicker mostly.